# YouTrack issues list Detail Level manipulation

Tags: youtrack

Question: is it possible to manipulate with issues list detail level some way other than button?

Story: there is a button in issue list where you can choose the presentation of issues in the list: TreeView, One-Line View, Compact View, Detailed View. I would like to give a link or query that specifies the view. Something like:

```
 http://link/issues?q=in:Pro_LG view:DetailedView
 http://link/issues?q=in:Documentation view:TreeView
```

Because if I present (share link, show people) some hierarchical task, I would like it to look like TreeView. And when I present the subset of issues (issues for build) I would like them to be in DetailedView.

And it is not very convenient to tell people "And don't forget to switch to tree view, after you open my link" =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible now. Here's the respective request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-15305.